# Gson with FileWriter doesn't write complete file

Tags: java, java-8, gson

I am creating an instance of `Gson` and writing with the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Writer writer = new FileWriter(location);
gson.toJson(data, writer);
```

This does write to the file, but the JSON object is incomplete and ends at line 7197 like this:

```
...
{
    "type": "RockCell"
},
{
    "type": "Flo
```

I have tried deleting and rerunning the code and it always stops writing at line 7197 in this exact way.

If I change the value of `data`, it ends at a different point (line 7182) but again does so consistently.

In both cases, the files are 106,496 bytes in size. This issue still occurs if pretty printing is disabled, but the files are always 49,152 bytes.

Comment: Do you close your FileWriter when you're done writing out to file? And if not, then why not?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you, I did forget to add that. It's working correctly now.

Comment: You're welcome. Closing as a duplicate to thousands of other similar questions. Please search first. A simple search on incomplete output from filewriter or something similar would have given you a solution.

Comment: Ill just say I could not figure this out until I stumbled upon this thread. Not sure if its a duplicate since the problem looks like its an issue with memory size at first with JSON.